# Thunderbird Search Folder broken "The mail server account me@me.com responded [NONEXISTANT] Unknown Mailbox: [Google Mail]/All Mail/folder"

Tags: thunderbird, gmail-imap

One of my search folders has broken. I now get a "The mail server account me@me.com responded [NONEXISTANT] Unknown Mailbox: [Google Mail]/All Mail/mysearchfolder" error on application start and whenever I try to access it.

Any idea what's causing it? The folder itself is accessible It's just not working as a search folder anymore.

Any ideas of a fix?

It's linked to a gmail mailbox if that makes a difference.

I don't like the idea of recreating the search folder as I've added a lot of entries into the filter list.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.